# List view inside scroll view is not working correctly

Tags: android, listview, adapter, expandablelistview

In My Scroll view i have a list and list is custom list view.I am using Expnadable list view to show list view inside scroll view.My Problem is taht when user scroll list then all of list data is not showing.
When i scroll down and move to bottom of list then  last item is not shown,and after that when scroll up then first item of list is not shown.
Then i tab on some other fragment and come bag to list view then last otem of list is shown but only half then item is shown.
Is there any scrolling issue.
Below is my code-

**my list in xml**
 `<ListView 
        android:id="@+id/my_post_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:divider="@color/post_title_bg"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>`

**and my code for loading adapter is -**

```
    postList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(mContext, mList,fm);
    postList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    ExpandableHeightListView.getListViewSize(postList);
    postList.setSelection(0);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Please see image added below- [image]

you can see whole image item is not showing .It shows half of item only.

Please help in soving this proble,.
Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Please see complete xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">



<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/user_profile_pic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>


 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/user_profile_pic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="user_name"/>

  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/user_email"
    android:layout_below="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="user_email"/>

       <ListView 
          android:id="@+id/my_post_listview" 
          android:layout_below="@+id/user_email"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:clickable="false" 
         android:divider="@color/post_title_bg" 
         android:dividerHeight="1dp" 
         android:visibility="gone"/>

       </RelativeLayout>

     </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why would you need a ListView inside a ScrollView? those two are not suppose to work together.

Comment: according to my app design above i have to show some contain and then list thats  why i have to use it.

Comment: Can you post your layout XML and also show exactly what you need? Perhaps there's a better way to achieve that, because a ListView inside a ScrollView won't really work.

Comment: I don't see how this can work smoothly. I would rethink the UX and come up with something that doesn't involve a scroll within a scroll. Android's widgets aren't built to handle inner scrolling on the same axis.

Comment: so how can i achive this kind of design,please give me any other way for this.